# Failure when using paster to backup CKAN

Tags: ckan, paster

I want to upgrade CKAN to it's newest version. Before I upgrade the packages, I want to backup everything. I'm using the following as my reference. http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.4.3/upgrade.html.

Another dev installed CKAN, who is no longer with the team. CKAN is up and running, I'm just trying to upgrade the software to a newer version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the error I'm getting when executing the paster command (either myself or root).

```
paster --plugin=ckan db dump demo_ckan_backup.pg_dump --config=demo.ckan.net.ini
```

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/paster", line 4, in <module>
command.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 93, in run
commands = get_commands()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/command.py", line 135, in get_commands
plugins = pluginlib.resolve_plugins(plugins)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/script/pluginlib.py", line 82, in resolve_plugins
pkg_resources.require(plugin)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Not Found: ckan (did you run python setup.py develop?)
```

Comment: RTFM http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/paster.html

Comment: Have you activate [virtualenv](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#install-ckan-into-a-python-virtual-environment)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move to:

```
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan
```

And then try it again.